# django compile form from URL parameters

Tags: django, design-patterns, workflow

This is my workflow:

> 1) view A : headers
>
> 2) view B : rows
>
> 3) form : one row with mixed data from 1 and 2

To compile form in 3) I need data that can be retrieved 
from 1): get the document, then in 2): reference of a specific row.

How can make the initial form values as what selected in 1) and 2)  ?

1) pass the needed values as URL parameters?

2) invert the workflow: create a form and then call the views?

3) ?